# Copy user input to char vector

Tags: c++

Quick disclaimer, this is a contrived example meant to simulate an issue I am seeing in my homework problem. To that end, using strings is out of the question; I can only use char arrays as per the instructor :(

What I am trying to do is continuously read input from the keyboard and store it in a `vector` . The problem is, whatever data I add to the `vector` is lost as soon as the `addData` function ends (when I try to view it, I see `\320\366\277_\377`). I believe this is due to the fact I am using a `vector<char*>`, so the `vector` can only use the data for as long as the `pointer` exists. However, my code cannot compile if I change it to a `vector<char>`, as I get errors saying `cannot convert char* to char`.

So, how can I save a **char array** (*not* a single char) to a vector element? Or, is there perhaps a better approach to this that would avoid the problem altogether?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 80;

// class declaration
class Example {
public:
    void getData ();
    void addData ( char * newData );
    void displayData ();

private:
    vector<char*> vec;
};

// main function
int main () {
    bool quitProg;
    int quit;
    quitProg = false;
    Example shoopDaWhoop; // buffers cannot overflow if you shoop da whoop
    while (!quitProg) {
        shoopDaWhoop.getData();
        shoopDaWhoop.displayData();
        cout << "Type 1 if you want to exit... ";
        cin >> quit;
        if (quit == 1) {
            quitProg = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void Example::getData () {
    char userInput [MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    cout << "Enter text: ";
    cin.get(userInput, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1, '\n');
    if ( cin.fail() ) { // data is invalid
        // clear and reset input stream
        cin.clear(ios::goodbit);
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
        // alert user they entered bad data
        cout << "That was bad data!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        // data is good, pass it to addData
        addData( userInput );
    }
}

void Example::addData ( char * newData ) {
    vec.push_back(newData);
    cout << "You entered: " << vec.back() << endl;


}
void Example::displayData () {
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Item " << i << ": " << vec[i] << endl;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `std::vector<std::string>`, that should "just work" with your existing code.

Since you cant do this with `std::string` (which would have been the proper way to use the language), the you a nested vector, like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > vex;  // notice the space between the '>' chars, older compilers may need it this way
```

Then in your `addData` function:

```
std::vector<char> tmp;

while(*newData)
   tmp.push_back(*newData++);

vec.push_back(tmp);
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use `string` in my homework assignment, unfortunately.

Comment: Do this then (see edit). Avoid doing you own memory management (don't use `new` with a raw pointer unless required by the assignment's rules.)

Answer (score 1):

Go with the `vector<char>`, but instead of

```
vec.push_back(newData);
```

Use:

```
size_t len = strlen(newData);
vec.insert(vec.end(), newData, newData + len);
```

Or does it actually need to be an vector of char arrays?

Comment: I need the vector to store a char array, like you said, not a single char.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<char*>` will only hold pointers - you want it to hold characters. To display the text, you'll have to iterate through the vector and print each character.

```
vector<char> vec;

void Example::addData ( char * newData ) {
  cout << "You entered: ";
  while (*newData) {
    vec.push_back(*newData);
    cout << (*newData);
    ++newData;
  }
  cout << endl";
}
```

If you want multiple strings you can use another vector.

Comment: That only stores individual characters to each vector element. I'm trying to store the entire char array to each vector element.

Comment: I believe what @Pubby8 is suggesting is that you can use `vector< vector< char > >`.  Of course, there are many ways you *could* attack this problem...with `new[]` and `delete[]` or whatever.  But hard to know exactly what you are allowed to use or not allowed to use...as you say "string is out of the question" but then you are using `vector`!